# Python pattern auto matching within the list

Tags: python-3.x, string, text, text-processing

I am trying to write a small script to group strings with similar patterns together. The following is my program snippet, which is working fine, but a little inaccurate.

```py
lst = ["report-2020.10.13", "report-2020.12.12", "analytics-2020.12.14", "sales-cda87", "analytics-2020.11.21", "sales-vu7sa"]

final = []
for pat in lst:
    pat = pat[:len(pat) // 2]
    ils = []
    for pat2 in lst:
        if pat2.startswith(pat):
            ils.append(pat2)
    final.append(tuple(ils))

finalls = list(set(final))
for f in finalls:
    print(f)
```

Also, I want the exact string pattern that groups the string. For example, from string list `["rep-10-01", "rep-10-02", "rep-11-06"]` I want `"rep-"` as a pattern.
Are there any improvements required? Or any libraries/modules that can help me out in first as well as second problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly suggest you to look into data structure called as Trie. That exactly does this for you. Link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Comment: Why does he need the Trie DS?   Python has the batteries - defaultdict can help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work as you expected:

```py
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    res = defaultdict(str)
    
    lst = ["report-2020.10.13", "report-2020.12.12", "analytics-2020.12.14",
           "sales-cda87", "analytics-2020.11.21", "sales-vu7sa"]
    
    #ll = ['rep-10-01', 'rep-10-02', 'rep-11-06']
    
    
    for pat in lst:
        pattern = pat.split('-')
        #print(pattern[0])  # real pattern - eg. report, sales, analytics
        
        res[pattern[0]] += pat+ ', '
        
    print(res)

      Output: 
    defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'report': 'report-2020.10.13, report-2020.12.12, ', 'analytics': 'analytics-2020.12.14, analytics-2020.11.21, ', 'sales': 'sales-cda87, sales-vu7sa, '})
```

Comment: @Atharva Kale does this post help you? If yes, please accept it, or ask other questions?

Comment: Yes. It does work, somehow. But what if my patterns consist more than one hyphens? And these hyphen separated patterns mean anything to me? (Which is my case). What could be done?

Comment: Glad that you find it's helpful.  Would you accept the answer then?  For the follow-up question, it's fine to post another question with some examples.